# Tensorflow: Saving a model to model.pb, to visualize it later

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I found the following code snippet to visualize a model which was saved to a `*.pb` file:

```
model_filename ='saved_model.pb'
with tf.Session() as sess:
    with gfile.FastGFile(path_to_model_pb, 'rb') as f:
        data = compat.as_bytes(f.read())
        sm = saved_model_pb2.SavedModel()
        sm.ParseFromString(data)
        g_in = tf.import_graph_def(sm.meta_graphs[0].graph_def)
        LOGDIR='.'
        train_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(LOGDIR)
        train_writer.add_graph(sess.graph)
```

Now I am struggling to create the `saved_model.pb` in the first place. If my session.run looks like this:

```
  _, cr_loss = sess.run([train_op,cross_entropy_loss],
                         feed_dict={input_image: images,
                                    correct_label: gt_images,
                                    keep_prob:  KEEP_PROB,
                                    learning_rate: LEARNING_RATE}
                        )
```

How do I save the graph contained in `train_op` to `saved_model.pb` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest way is to use [`tf.train.write_graph`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/write_graph). Usually, you just need to do something like:

```
tf.train.write_graph(my_graph, path_to_model_pb,
                     'saved_model.pb', as_text=False)
```

`my_graph` can be [`tf.get_default_graph()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/get_default_graph) if you are using the default graph or any other [`tf.Graph`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Graph) (or [`tf.GraphDef`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/GraphDef)) object.

Note that this saves the graph definition, which is ok to visualize it, but if you have variables their values will not be saved there unless you [freeze the graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45466020/how-to-export-keras-h5-to-tensorflow-pb/45466355#45466355) first (since those are only in the session object, not the graph itself).

Comment: Thanks. But what do I have to do so that tf.get_default_graph() really returns the graph I just built? Please see the updated original question for some specification.

Comment: @user1934212 I've updated the answer. If your graph was created somewhere else (e.g. the previous function in the call stack), put the code inside a context like `with my_graph.as_default():` and then  [`tf.get_default_graph()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/get_default_graph) will return the right graph.

Comment: If the graph was created somehwere else, would `train_op` from my original question be identical to `my_graph` in `with my_graph.as_default()` and if not, how would I get from `train_op` to `my_graph` ?

Comment: @user1934212 Well, I can't tell what is the value of `train_op` from your code, but assuming it is a [`tf.Operation`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Operation) or a [`tf.Tensor`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Tensor), you can then get the graph simply as `train_op.graph`.

Comment: What is `path_to_model_pb`? Why does this parameter exist along with the `'saved_model.pb'` one?

Comment: @SomethingSomething Look at [the docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.15/api_docs/python/tf/io/write_graph) of the function, it is just the directory. If you see [the source](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v1.15.0/tensorflow/python/framework/graph_io.py), you'll see it's a very simple wrapper to another function and it just joins them both, not sure why they designed it like that...

Answer (score 2):

I will cover this problem in steps:

To visualize variables like weights, biases use **tf.summary.histogram**

```
weights = {
    'h1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_input, n_hidden_1])),
    'h2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_1, n_hidden_2])),
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_2, n_classes]))
}
tf.summary.histogram("weight1", weights['h1'])
tf.summary.histogram("weight2", weights['h2'])
tf.summary.histogram("weight3", weights['out'])
biases = {
    'b1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_1])),
    'b2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_2])),
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_classes]))
}
tf.summary.histogram("bias1", biases['b1'])
tf.summary.histogram("bias2", biases['b2'])
tf.summary.histogram("bias3", biases['out'])
cost = tf.sqrt(tf.reduce_mean(tf.squared_difference(pred, y)))
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate).minimize(cost)
tf.summary.scalar('rmse', cost)
```

Then while training include following code.

```
summaries = tf.summary.merge_all()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    # Get data
    writer = tf.summary.FileWriter("histogram_example", sess.graph)
    # Training cycle
            # Run optimization op (backprop) and cost op (to get loss value)
            summ, p, _, c = sess.run([summ, pred, optimizer, cost], feed_dict={x: batch_x,
                                                          y: batch_y,})
            writer.add_summary(summ, global_step=epoch*total_batch+i)
```