# How can I rename the input tensor name of an op in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

My graph definition before removing the dropout layers looks like this :

```
fc6/BiasAdd : BiasAdd ( [u'fc6/Conv2D', u'fc6/biases/read'] )
fc6/Relu : Relu ( [u'fc6/BiasAdd'] )
dropout/keep_prob : Const ( [] )
dropout/Shape : Shape ( [u'fc6/Relu'] )
dropout/random_uniform/min : Const ( [] )
dropout/random_uniform/max : Const ( [] )
dropout/random_uniform/RandomUniform : RandomUniform ( [u'dropout/Shape'] )
dropout/random_uniform/sub : Sub ( [u'dropout/random_uniform/max', u'dropout/random_uniform/min'] )
dropout/random_uniform/mul : Mul ( [u'dropout/random_uniform/RandomUniform', u'dropout/random_uniform/sub'] )
dropout/random_uniform : Add ( [u'dropout/random_uniform/mul', u'dropout/random_uniform/min'] )
dropout/add : Add ( [u'dropout/keep_prob', u'dropout/random_uniform'] )
dropout/Floor : Floor ( [u'dropout/add'] )
dropout/Inv : Inv ( [u'dropout/keep_prob'] )
dropout/mul : Mul ( [u'fc6/Relu', u'dropout/Inv'] )
dropout/mul_1 : Mul ( [u'dropout/mul', u'dropout/Floor'] )
fc7/weights : Const ( [] )
fc7/weights/read : Identity ( [u'fc7/weights'] )
fc7/Conv2D : Conv2D ( [u'dropout/mul_1', u'fc7/weights/read'] )
```

in format `node.name : node.type node.input`

After removing the dropout layers, I must find out how can I change the input tensor name of a specific layer. After removing dropout layers the graph looks like this :

```
fc6/BiasAdd : BiasAdd ( [u'fc6/Conv2D', u'fc6/biases/read'] )
fc6/Relu : Relu ( [u'fc6/BiasAdd'] )
fc7/weights : Const ( [] )
fc7/weights/read : Identity ( [u'fc7/weights'] )
fc7/Conv2D : Conv2D ( [u'dropout/mul_1', u'fc7/weights/read'] )
```

But, as you can see the `fc7/Conv2D` operation still expects `dropout/mul_1` as an input. Because of that I am getting this error :

**ValueError: graph_def is invalid at node u'fc7/Conv2D': Input tensor 'dropout/mul_1:0' not found in graph_def..**

I want to change expected input tensor name of the node - operation to `fc6/BiasAdd`, for the network to be valid. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no straightforward way of doing something like that. In general, the computation graph can be augmented with new operations, but the existing nodes cannot be modified. There are three possible paths you can follow:

- The easiest thing would be to leave the dropout layer as it is, and simply pass a constant `keep_prob` or 1 (for example using a [`tf.placeholder_with_default`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/placeholder_with_default)). You will still have some minor overhead (I think, I don't know if the implementation of dropout bypasses the operation with a probability of 1), but it will probably be unnoticeable.
- Make a copy of the graph in another [`tf.Graph`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Graph) object without the dropout layers and then copy the variable values from the session in the first one to a session in the new one (e.g. with [`load()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Variable#load)).
- Actually edit the graph. Although not its main intended usage, it is possible to edit the graph to some extent. The model [`tf.contrib.graph_editor`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/contrib.graph_editor) implements a number of operations to that end. In your case, you are probably looking for something like [`tf.contrib.graph_editor.swap_inputs`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/graph_editor/swap_inputs). The drawback here is that these operations must be done "offline", that is, with no active sessions using the graph. That means that variable values would in principle not be saved. You can either [checkpoint the model](http://cv-tricks.com/tensorflow-tutorial/save-restore-tensorflow-models-quick-complete-tutorial/), manually save the variable values to NumPy arrays and restore them after the graph is modified or, if you are done training and only intend to use your model for inference, you can also [freeze the graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45466020/how-to-export-keras-h5-to-tensorflow-pb/45466355#45466355). In any case, you have to take care of it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but whatever I tried (first approach) the probability stays in 0.5, can you give me a quick example ? FYI I have available only the .ckpt and .pb files (of the model) that I can load and read and not the definition of the graph itself. PS: The third approach seems good also (any examples?).

Comment: @KonstantinosMonachopoulos Oh well, if that is the case, I see two things you can do: 1) Load the graph and restore as usual, the manually provide the `keep_prob` when you call `run` (like `feed_dict={'dropout/keep_prob:0': 1, ...}`) 2) Load the `tf.GraphDef` object, then use [Graph Editor](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/contrib.graph_editor) to reroute as you need and _then_ restore the checkpoint.

Comment: Thank you very much, setting probs to 1 during inference gives a solution, however I would prefer to remove dropout completely to make sure that there is nothing there that ruins my output when I inference using a quantized graph (my output is a mess in this case and I am trying to find out why). I will try the Graph editor to find a potential solution there. Again, thank you, any extra information would be appreciated.

Comment: @KonstantinosMonachopoulos I'm afraid I don't have any real experience with Graph Editor, but at least I've run [the example](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/graph_editor/examples/edit_graph_example.py) and it seems to work without much effort...

Comment: The second approach is working perfectly ! Thanks :) ! !