# Obtain input_array and output_array items to convert model to tflite format

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

**PS. Please dont point me to [converting Keras model directly to tflite](http://Traceback%20(most%20recent%20call%20last):%20%20%20File%20%22/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/tflite_convert%22,%20line%2011,%20in%20%3Cmodule%3E%20%20%20%20%20sys.exit(main())%20%20%20File%20%22/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/lite/python/tflite_convert.py%22,%20line%20412,%20in%20main%20%20%20%20%20app.run(main=run_main,%20argv=sys.argv[:1])%20%20%20File%20%22/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py%22,%20line%20125,%20in%20run%20%20%20%20%20_sys.exit(main(argv))%20%20%20File%20%22/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/lite/python/tflite_convert.py%22,%20line%20408,%20in%20run_main%20%20%20%20%20_convert_model(tflite_flags)%20%20%20File%20%22/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/lite/python/tflite_convert.py%22,%20line%20100,%20in%20_convert_model%20%20%20%20%20converter%20=%20_get_toco_converter(flags)%20%20%20File%20%22/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/lite/python/tflite_convert.py%22,%20line%2087,%20in%20_get_toco_converter%20%20%20%20%20return%20converter_fn(**converter_kwargs)%20%20%20File%20%22/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/lite/python/lite.py%22,%20line%20368,%20in%20from_keras_model_file%20%20%20%20%20keras_model%20=%20_keras.models.load_model(model_file)%20%20%20File%20%22/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/saving.py%22,%20line%20230,%20in%20load_model%20%20%20%20%20model%20=%20model_from_config(model_config,%20custom_objects=custom_objects)%20%20%20File%20%22/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/saving.py%22,%20line%20310,%20in%20model_from_config%20%20%20%20%20return%20deserialize(config,%20custom_objects=custom_objects)%20%20%20File%20%22/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/serialization.py%22,%20line%2064,%20in%20deserialize%20%20%20%20%20printable_module_name='layer')%20%20%20File%20%22/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/generic_utils.py%22,%20line%20173,%20in%20deserialize_keras_object%20%20%20%20%20list(custom_objects.items())))%20%20%20File%20%22/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/network.py%22,%20line%201302,%20in%20from_config%20%20%20%20%20process_node(layer,%20node_data)%20%20%20File%20%22/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/network.py%22,%20line%201260,%20in%20process_node%20%20%20%20%20layer(input_tensors[0],%20**kwargs)%20%20%20File%20%22/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py%22,%20line%20757,%20in%20__call__%20%20%20%20%20outputs%20=%20self.call(inputs,%20*args,%20**kwargs)%20%20%20File%20%22/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/core.py%22,%20line%20739,%20in%20call%20%20%20%20%20return%20self.function(inputs,%20**arguments)%20%20%20File%20%22/Users/sparker0i/face-recognition/utils.py%22,%20line%2035,%20in%20LRN2D%20%20%20%20%20return%20tf.nn.lrn(x,%20alpha=1e-4,%20beta=0.75)%20NameError:%20name%20'tf'%20is%20not%20defined) as my .h5 file would fail to convert to .tflite directly. I somehow managed to convert my .h5 file to .pb**

I have followed [this](https://github.com/krasserm/face-recognition/blob/master/face-recognition-convert.ipynb) Jupyter notebook for face recognition using Keras. I then saved my model to a `model.h5` file, then converted it to a frozen graph, `model.pb` using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45466355/2451763).

Now I want to use my tensorflow file in Android. For this I will need to have Tensorflow Lite, which requires me to convert my model into a `.tflite` format.

For this, I'm trying to follow the official guidelines for it [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/convert/python_api#exporting_a_graphdef_from_file_). As you can see there, it requires `input_array` and `output_array` arrays. How do I obtain details of these things from my `model.pb` file?

Comment: Just get the input and output tensors from the graph. Put them in arrays.

Comment: Shubham's answer is correct. But note that if you export to a SavedModel or directly from a Keras model using TFLiteConverter's python interface, you do not have to specify the input and outputs as they are already included in the representation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`input arrays` and `output arrays` are the arrays which store input and output tensors respectively.

> They intend to inform the `TFLiteConverter` about the input and output tensors which will be used at the time of inference.

**For a Keras model,**

The input tensor is the placeholder tensor of the first layer.

```
input_tensor = model.layers[0].input
```

The output tensor may relate with a activation function.

```
output_tensor = model.layers[ LAST_LAYER_INDEX ].output
```

**For a Frozen Graph,**

```
import tensorflow as tf
gf = tf.GraphDef()   
m_file = open('model.pb','rb')
gf.ParseFromString(m_file.read())
```

We get the names of the nodes,

```
for n in gf.node:
    print( n.name )
```

To get the tensor,

```
tensor = n.op
```

The input tensor may be a placeholder tensor. Output tensor is the tensor which you run using `session.run()`

**For conversion, we get,**

```
input_array =[ input_tensor ]
output_array = [ output_tensor ]
```

Comment: You should also look out [this](https://lutzroeder.github.io/netron/) awesome tool that lets you visualize a model from a lot of different formats. I used it to check my input/output tensor names.

Comment: Hi, @Romzie. I'm new at tensorflow. Could you please explaint how to use that tool. Is first node input and the last node output tensor?

Comment: @MSK Can you confirm if the first/last node are the input/output nodes?