# Tensorflow : Generate freeze graph without having node_names

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have some (old) Tensorflow model that have been created by another person.

For each of these model, I want to create frozen graph.

My models can be either `Saved Model` :

```
+--- name.txt
+--- saved_model.pb
+--- variables
|   +--- variables.data-00000-of-00001
|   +--- variables.index
```

Or `Meta Graphs` :

```
+--- export.data-00000-of-00001
+--- export.index
+--- export.meta
```

So, I tried to create frozen graphs using these functions:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import os

def frozenGraph_SavedGraph(modelFolder, outputFolder, toolsFilepath)
    networkGraph = "saved_model.pb"
    networkCheckpoint = "variables/variables.data-00000-of-00001"

    args = "--checkpoint_version=1\
            --input_graph=" + modelFolder + "/" + networkGraph + "\
            --input_checkpoint=" + modelFolder + "/" + networkCheckpoint + "\
            --output_graph=" + outputFolder + "\
            --input_binary=true"

    os.system(toolsFilepath + "/freeze_graph.py " + args)

def frozenGraph_Metagraph(modelFolder, outputFolder, toolsFilepath)
    networkMeta = "export.meta"
    networkCheckpoint = "export.data-00000-of-00001"

    args = "--checkpoint_version=1\
            --input_meta_graph=" + modelFolder + "/" + networkMeta + "\
            --input_checkpoint=" + modelFolder + "/" + networkCheckpoint + "\
            --output_graph=" + outputFolder + "\
            --input_binary=true"

    os.system(toolsFilepath + "/freeze_graph.py " + args)


toolsFilepath = os.path.dirname(tf.__file__) + "/python/tools"
savedGraphFilepath = [PATH/TO/SAVED_GRAPH]
metaGraphFilepath = [PATH/TO/META_GRAPH]
outputFolder = "/output"

frozenGraph_SavedGraph(savedGraphFilepath, outputFolder, toolsFilepath)
frozenGraph_Metagraph(metaGraphFilepath, outputFolder, toolsFilepath)
```

But for both of these function, I get the error message :

```
You need to supply the name of a node to --output_node_names.
```

The problem is that I don't think that I have the node names in the file that are available to me (those listed above).

Is there a way to generate frozen graphs without these informations ? (Or a way to retrieve them ?)

EDIT :

I tried to retrieve node names from the graph using this code :

```
def printNames_Metagraph(modelFolder):
    networkMeta = "export.meta"
    networkCheckpoint = "export.data-00000-of-00001"

    saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(modelFolder + "/" + networkMeta)
    sess = tf.Session()
    saver.restore(sess, modelFolder + "/" + networkCheckpoint)
    graph = sess.graph

    print([node.name for node in graph.as_graph_def().node])
```

But it throws a lot of error and warnings :

```
2019-03-14 16:40:42.973341: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_def_util.cc:357] Op TensorArray is deprecated. It will cease to work in GraphDef version 16. Use TensorArrayV3.
2019-03-14 16:40:42.973738: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_def_util.cc:357] Op TensorArrayScatter is deprecated. It will cease to work in GraphDef version 19. Use TensorArrayGradV3.
2019-03-14 16:40:42.974148: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_def_util.cc:357] Op TensorArrayRead is deprecated. It will cease to work in GraphDef version 16. Use TensorArrayReadV3.
2019-03-14 16:40:42.974740: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_def_util.cc:357] Op TensorArrayWrite is deprecated. It will cease to work in GraphDef version 16. Use TensorArrayWriteV3.
2019-03-14 16:40:42.975107: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_def_util.cc:357] Op TensorArraySize is deprecated. It will cease to work in GraphDef version 16. Use TensorArraySizeV3.
2019-03-14 16:40:42.975378: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_def_util.cc:357] Op TensorArrayGather is deprecated. It will cease to work in GraphDef version 16. Use TensorArrayGatherV3.
WARNING: Logging before flag parsing goes to stderr.
W0314 16:40:43.424403 10080 meta_graph.py:897] The saved meta_graph is possibly from an older release:
'model_variables' collection should be of type 'byte_list', but instead is of type 'node_list'.
2019-03-14 16:40:43.439121: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2
W0314 16:40:43.442324 10080 deprecation.py:323] From [MY/PATH/]lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\saver.py:1276: checkpoint_exists (from tensorflow.python.training.checkpoint_management) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use standard file APIs to check for files with this prefix.
2019-03-14 16:40:44.049683: W tensorflow/core/util/tensor_slice_reader.cc:95] Could not open [MY/PATH2/]/models\PATH/TO/METAGRAPH/export.data-00000-of-00001: Data loss: not an sstable (bad magic number): perhaps your file is in a different file format and you need to use a different restore operator?
2019-03-14 16:40:44.052551: W tensorflow/core/util/tensor_slice_reader.cc:95] Could not open [MY/PATH2/]/models\PATH/TO/METAGRAPH/export.data-00000-of-00001: Data loss: not an sstable (bad magic number): perhaps your file is in a different file format and you need to use a different restore operator?
2019-03-14 16:40:44.052574: W tensorflow/core/util/tensor_slice_reader.cc:95] Could not open [MY/PATH2/]/models\PATH/TO/METAGRAPH/export.data-00000-of-00001: Data loss: not an sstable (bad magic number): perhaps your file is in a different file format and you need to use a different restore operator?
2019-03-14 16:40:44.053005: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1431] OP_REQUIRES failed at save_restore_tensor.cc:175 : Data loss: Unable to open table file [MY/PATH2/]/models\PATH/TO/METAGRAPH/export.data-00000-of-00001: Data loss: not an sstable (bad magic number): perhaps your file is in a different file format and you need to use a different restore operator?

 ...

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "[MY/PATH/]lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1335, in _do_call
    return fn(*args)
  File "[MY/PATH/]lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1320, in _run_fn
    options, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, run_metadata)
  File "[MY/PATH/]lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1408, in _call_tf_sessionrun
    run_metadata)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.DataLossError: Unable to open table file [MY/PATH2/]/models\PATH/TO/METAGRAPH/export.data-00000-of-00001: Data loss: not an sstable (bad magic number): perhaps your file is in a different file format and you need to use a different restore operator?
     [[{{node save/RestoreV2_311}}]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "[MY/PATH2/]Main.py", line 80, in <module>
    printNames()
  File "[MY/PATH2/]Main.py", line 64, in printNames
    saver.restore(sess, modelFolder + "/" + networkWeightsFile)
  File "[MY/PATH/]lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\saver.py", line 1286, in restore
    {self.saver_def.filename_tensor_name: save_path})
  File "[MY/PATH/]lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 930, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "[MY/PATH/]lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1153, in _run
    feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
  File "[MY/PATH/]lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1329, in _do_run
    run_metadata)
  File "[MY/PATH/]lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1349, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.DataLossError: Unable to open table file [MY/PATH2/]/models\PATH/TO/METAGRAPH/export.data-00000-of-00001: Data loss: not an sstable (bad magic number): perhaps your file is in a different file format and you need to use a different restore operator?
     [[node save/RestoreV2_311 (defined at [MY/PATH2/]Main.py:62) ]]

Original stack trace for 'save/RestoreV2_311':
  File "[MY/PATH2/]Main.py", line 80, in <module>
    printNames()
  File "[MY/PATH2/]Main.py", line 62, in printNames
    saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(modelFolder + "/" + networkArcFile)
  File "[MY/PATH/]\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\saver.py", line 1445, in import_meta_graph
    meta_graph_or_file, clear_devices, import_scope, **kwargs)[0]
  File "[MY/PATH/]\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\saver.py", line 1467, in _import_meta_graph_with_return_elements
    **kwargs))
  File "[MY/PATH/]\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\meta_graph.py", line 855, in import_scoped_meta_graph_with_return_elements
    return_elements=return_elements)
  File "[MY/PATH/]\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\deprecation.py", line 507, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "[MY/PATH/]\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\importer.py", line 443, in import_graph_def
    _ProcessNewOps(graph)
  File "[MY/PATH/]\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\importer.py", line 236, in _ProcessNewOps
    for new_op in graph._add_new_tf_operations(compute_devices=False):  # pylint: disable=protected-access
  File "[MY/PATH/]\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 3612, in _add_new_tf_operations
    for c_op in c_api_util.new_tf_operations(self)
  File "[MY/PATH/]\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 3612, in <listcomp>
    for c_op in c_api_util.new_tf_operations(self)
  File "[MY/PATH/]\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 3504, in _create_op_from_tf_operation
    ret = Operation(c_op, self)
  File "[MY/PATH/]\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 1961, in __init__
    self._traceback = tf_stack.extract_stack()


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Notes :

- Using Tensorflow 1.13.1 with Python 3
- The models I am trying to load might use an old version of Tensorflow with the first version of checkpoints
- The models are binary files

Comment: Graph freezing is based on [`tf.graph_util.convert_variables_to_constants`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/graph_util/convert_variables_to_constants) (in the future `tf.compat.v1.graph_util.convert_variables_to_constants`), you can call it from your code (see for example [this function I posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45466355/1782792)). If you want to preserve the whole graph in any case, you can just say that all nodes are output nodes. However, a graph where you don't know the outputs is not very useful, because you need those for evaluation.

Comment: You can try to "guess" which nodes are outputs through some heuristic, for example looking for nodes that are not connected to any other following node. However, this may not give you the right result, an output node may actually be connected to another node (e.g. for metrics or something else) and a non-output may not have outgoing connections (e.g. if it is an unused intermediate value).