# Keras h5 to Tensorflow serving in 2019?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-serving

i tried to follow this tutorial on how to convert a Keras H5 Model zu ProtoBuff and serving it using Tensorflow Serve:
https://towardsdatascience.com/deploying-keras-models-using-tensorflow-serving-and-flask-508ba00f1037

That tutorial among many other resources on the web use "tf.saved_model.simple_save", which is deprecated and removed by now (March 2019).
Converting the h5 into pb using freeze_session as shown here:
[How to export Keras .h5 to tensorflow .pb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45466020/how-to-export-keras-h5-to-tensorflow-pb)

Seems to miss a "serve" Tag, as the tensorflow_model_server outputs:

`Loading servable: {name: ImageClassifier version: 1} failed: Not found: Could not find meta graph def matching supplied tags: { serve }. To inspect available tag-sets in the SavedModel, please use the SavedModel CLI: saved_model_cli`

checked it with saved_model_cli, there are no tags.

What is the way to make a h5 model serveable in tensorflow_server nowadays?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**NOTE**: This applies to TF 2.0+

I'm assuming you have your Keras model in `model.h5`.
Firstly, just load the model with tensorflow's implementation of Keras:

```
from tensorflow import keras
model = keras.models.load_model('model.h5')
```

Then, simply export a SavedModel

```
keras.experimental.export_saved_model(model, 'path_to_saved_model')
```

Finally, apply any transformation you nomally d to go from `SavedModel` to the `.pb` inference file (e.g.: freezing, optimizing for inference, etc)

You can hve more details and a full example in TF's [official guide for saving and serializing models in TF 2.0](https://www.tensorflow.org/alpha/guide/keras/saving_and_serializing)

Comment: Thank you for your Reply. Do i have to have a specific version of keras? i installed keras using "pip3 install keras". When using your code, it exists with the error "AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python.keras' has no attribute 'experimental'"

Comment: That's what I meant by "tensorflow's implementation of Keras". Don't `import keras`, the `from tensorflow import keras` part is very important

Comment: I did not import anything else, plain what you wrote. But now i noticed: on my local machine he can not find "experimental", and in a google collab VM he does find "experimental", but not "export_saved_model". So i guess i have a problem with the versions somewhere. Thank you for your input so far, will try to solve that first somehow

Comment: What TF version do you have installed?

Comment: Locally 1.5.0, and google Collab even runs 1.13.0. So TF 2.0 just recently released and i need to update more often. Will figure out how to use TF2 with my CPU  (had to downgrade the TF Version once because my CPU does not support a Commandset newer TF Versions are compiled with) and then try again. Thanks so far!

Comment: Yes, TF 1.5 is definitely not supporting this. Version 1.13 might, under different names. I do refer to the alpha version of 2.0 because you asked how this is done "in 2019". TF2 will be out in a matter of months and that will be the "new" way to do this.

Comment: Why does 1.3 support it and 1.5 not., isnt 1.5 newer than 1.3? So i will try to find a documentation on 1.3 and the keras.experimental then to find out the right name for the "save" method

Comment: It's 1.13 (thirteen), not 1.3 (Amended my previous incorrect comment that wrongly stated 1.13 would be the last TF1 release before TF2. The last v1 stable release is TF 1.15)

Comment: API is updated to `model.save('path_to_saved_model', save_format="tf")` now