# how to convert .h5 file to .pb file?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-serving

How do I convert a .h5 weight file to .pb file ? I trained keras pre-trained model and saved the file as something.h5 . How do i convert it to .pb file for using it for tensorflow serving ?

P.S: Don't degrade the question, I couldn't find any solution online. Do mention the reason why you degraded the question. Otherwise, help with solving the question.

Comment: did you look here [how-to-export-keras-h5-to-tensorflow-pb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45466020/how-to-export-keras-h5-to-tensorflow-pb)

Comment: does this answer your question? https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/57310/how-to-convert-model-h5-to-model-pb or may be this: https://www.dlology.com/blog/how-to-convert-trained-keras-model-to-tensorflow-and-make-prediction/

Comment: I don't believe You searched on the net - those answers in comments  are right from the first page of results from google

Comment: Tensorflow also has a tutorial on saving .h5 and .pb

Comment: @jakub ofc they have a tutorial . I couldn't underatand much over there thats why posted it on stackoverflow  !

Comment: -1 you do not show what you have already tried, and tensorflow has gone through lots of effort to publish excellent tutorials such as [Save and load models](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/save_and_load#save_the_entire_model) and [Using the SavedModel format](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/saved_model#creating_a_savedmodel_from_keras).

Answer (score 4):

```py
import tensorflow as tf
model = tf.keras.models.load_model(keras_model_path)
tf.saved_model.save(model, saved_model_path)
```

Bingo.

Comment: ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

Comment: That is too little information for me to be able to help you. It sounds like you don't have something installed. but I don't know what. I suggest you refer to the official documentation for the basics of loading and saving: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/save_and_load. This document covers both h5 and pb file formats.

Comment: instead of `tf.saved_model.save(model, saved_model_path)`, you can also use `model.save(saved_model_path)`

Comment: if you do not include an extension, it will default to savedmodel format