# Cannot convert tf.keras.layers.ConvLSTM2D layer to open vino intermediate representation

Tags: tensorflow, keras, lstm, intel, openvino

I am trying to convert a trained model in tensorflow to [Open VINO](https://docs.openvinotoolkit.org/latest/_docs_MO_DG_prepare_model_convert_model_Convert_Model_From_TensorFlow.html#tensorflow_specific_conversion_params) Intermediate Representation.

I have a model of the form given below

```
class Conv3DModel(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Conv3DModel, self).__init__()
        # Convolutions
        self.conv1 = tf.compat.v2.keras.layers.Conv3D(32, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', name="conv1", data_format='channels_last')
        self.pool1 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPool3D(pool_size=(2, 2, 2), data_format='channels_last')
        self.conv2 = tf.compat.v2.keras.layers.Conv3D(64, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', name="conv1", data_format='channels_last')
        self.pool2 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPool3D(pool_size=(2, 2,2), data_format='channels_last')

        # LSTM & Flatten
        self.convLSTM =tf.keras.layers.ConvLSTM2D(40, (3, 3))
        self.flatten =  tf.keras.layers.Flatten(name="flatten")

        # Dense layers
        self.d1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu', name="d1")
        self.out = tf.keras.layers.Dense(6, activation='softmax', name="output")


    def call(self, x):
        x = self.conv1(x)
        x = self.pool1(x)
        x = self.conv2(x)
        x = self.pool2(x)
        x = self.convLSTM(x)
        x = self.flatten(x)
        x = self.d1(x)
        return self.out(x)
```

I tried to convert the model into IR. The model is [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OdzRQRYVB6KOZYeTxmu-SkwkqMrOCUK7/view?usp=sharing) .

I have trained this model in tensorflow 1.15. Tensorflow 2.0 is currently not supported.

Now I tried to run the command

python3 /opt/intel/openvino/deployment_tools/model_optimizer/mo_tf.py --saved_model_dir jester_trained_models/3dcnn-basic/  --output_dir /home/deepanshu/open_vino/udacity_project_custom_model/

Now i got the following error

**Model Optimizer arguments:**

Common parameters:

- Path to the Input Model: None
- Path for generated IR: /home/deepanshu/open_vino/udacity_project_custom_model/
- IR output name: saved_model
- Log level: ERROR
- Batch: Not specified, inherited from the model
- Input layers: Not specified, inherited from the model
- Output layers: Not specified, inherited from the model
- Input shapes: Not specified, inherited from the model
- Mean values: Not specified
- Scale values: Not specified
- Scale factor: Not specified
- Precision of IR: FP32
- Enable fusing: True
- Enable grouped convolutions fusing: True
- Move mean values to preprocess section: False
- Reverse input channels: False

TensorFlow specific parameters:

- Input model in text protobuf format: False
- Path to model dump for TensorBoard: None
- List of shared libraries with TensorFlow custom layers implementation: None
- Update the configuration file with input/output node names: None
- Use configuration file used to generate the model with Object Detection API: None
- Operations to offload: None
- Patterns to offload: None
- Use the config file: None

Model Optimizer version: 2020.1.0-61-gd349c3ba4a

**[ ERROR ] Unexpected exception happened during extracting attributes for node conv3d_model/conv_lst_m2d/bias/Read/ReadVariableOp. Original exception message: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc9 in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)**

As far as  I can see it is the tf.keras.layers.ConvLSTM2D(40, (3, 3)) causing problems . I am kind of stuck here . Can anyone tell me where can I proceed further ?

Thanks

## Edit to the question

Now I rejected the above tensorflow implementation and used keras . My h5 model developed was converted into .pb format using this [post](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-distribution-of-openvino-toolkit/topic/820599).

Now I ran the model optimizer on this .pb file. Using the command

`python3 /opt/intel/openvino/deployment_tools/model_optimizer/mo_tf.py --input_model /home/deepanshu/ml_playground/jester_freezed/tf_model.pb  --output_dir /home/deepanshu/open_vino/udacity_project_custom_model/  --input_shape=[1,30,64,64,1] --data_type FP32`

Now i am facing another issue . The issue here is point no. **97** on this [post](https://docs.openvinotoolkit.org/latest/_docs_MO_DG_prepare_model_Model_Optimizer_FAQ.html).

So my model contains a cycle and model optimizer does not know a way to convert it. Has anybody faced this issue before ?

Please help.

Here is the [model](https://drive.google.com/file/d/16RbBRBctz8BvxAQW3Qju2R6gErz-mu5i/view?usp=sharing) .

Here is the defination of the model in keras

```py
from keras.models import Sequential

from keras.layers import Conv3D , MaxPool3D,Flatten ,Dense

from keras.layers.convolutional_recurrent import ConvLSTM2D

import keras


model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv3D(32, (3, 3, 3), 

         name="conv1" , input_shape=(30, 64, 64,1) ,  data_format='channels_last',

        activation='relu') )

model.add(MaxPool3D(pool_size=(2, 2, 2), data_format='channels_last'))

model.add(Conv3D(64, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', name="conv2", data_format='channels_last'))

model.add(MaxPool3D(pool_size=(2, 2,2), data_format='channels_last'))

model.add(ConvLSTM2D(40, (3, 3)))

model.add(Flatten(name="flatten"))

model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu', name="d1"))

model.add(Dense(6, activation='softmax', name="output"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the script to convert from h5 to .pb suggested by intel was not good enough. Always use the code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45466020/how-to-export-keras-h5-to-tensorflow-pb) to convert your keras model to **.pb**.

Once you obtain your **.pb** file now convert your model to IR using

```
python3 /opt/intel/openvino/deployment_tools/model_optimizer/mo_tf.py --input_model ml_playground/try_directory/tf_model.pb   --output_dir /home/deepanshu/open_vino/udacity_project_custom_model/  --input_shape=[1,30,64,64,1] --data_type FP32
```

After the execution of this script we can obtain the intermediate representation of the keras model.