# Runtime error on loading intermediate representation open vino

Tags: intel, openvino

This question follows from my earlier [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60606297/cannot-convert-tf-keras-layers-convlstm2d-layer-to-open-vino-intermediate-repres/60793062#60793062) . I had converted this keras model to .pb. The I also successfully converted this .pb to intermediate representation of Open VINO.  The model is available in the attachment of **last answer** of this [post](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-distribution-of-openvino-toolkit/topic/849772) at intel developer forum.

If you got this model. Now you can load the model like this .

```py
model_path = 'jester_freezed/IR/model/tf_model.xml'
from openvino.inference_engine import IENetwork, IECore
import os

def load_to_IE(model_xml, cpu_extension=None):
    #Load the Inference Engine API
    plugin = IECore()


    # Load IR files into their related class

    model_bin = os.path.splitext(model_xml)[0] + ".bin"

    net = IENetwork(model=model_xml, weights=model_bin)

    return net

net = load_to_IE(model_path)
```

Here is the full error.

RuntimeError: Check 'PartialShape::broadcast_merge_into(pshape, get_input_partial_shape(i), autob)' failed at /teamcity/work/scoring_engine_build/releases_2020_1/ngraph/src/ngraph/node.cpp:890:
While validating node 'Add[Add_43](Convolution_41: float{1,40,12,12}, Constant_42: float{40}) -> (??)':
Argument shapes are inconsistent.

My open vino version is 2020.1.

There are no resources available to debug this error. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: hi, any progress with this problem , i am facing the same , i trained openvino text_detection with image size width 200px and height 120px, some how with default setting i can train my mode but trying that sample with text_detection c++ sample i got error, here is a question i asked on intel community please have a look https://community.intel.com/t5/Intel-Distribution-of-OpenVINO/any-documentation-for-training-text-detection/m-p/1193276

Comment: Hi how about [this](https://docs.openvinotoolkit.org/latest/omz_models_intel_text_recognition_0012_description_text_recognition_0012.html) may be. I gave up the this project and open vino , the Edge TPU from Google is much better choice , when it comes to performance , documentation and support. I have tried the coral board , the raspberry pi  with Edge TPU and the NCS 2. I found the tflite paradigm much better to use and it performs much better.