# Error while converting tensorflow model to tensorflow lite (.h5 to .tflite) = ValueError: bad marshal data (unknown type code)

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite, yolo

I am using a pre-trained keras based and tensorflow based model with yolov2 architecture for potholes detection and I'm getting an error while converting my tensorflow model to tensorflow lite

```
from tensorflow.contrib import lite

converter = lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model_file( 'model.h5' )
model = converter.convert()
file = open( 'model.tflite' , 'wb' )
file.write( model )
```

Comment: Do you know whether there are any custom_ops and/or controlflow ops in your model? I would suggest you to use TF2.x with  `converter = tf.compat.v1.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model_file( 'model.h5' ),
converter.experimental_new_converter = True`. Check [TF_website](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/performance/post_training_integer_quant) for examples.

Comment: Thx for the quick reply! Unfortunately, that didn't work. I get the same error :(

Comment: If you can share the model file, I can help. Finding root-cause is difficult without looking into the model. Thanks

Comment: Sure! https://drive.google.com/open?id=1VwViHDdc4W8t28rMiuGjxChiAtFxMAjN

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest going for a longer but tested path.

1) Convert your model directly as `.pb` frozen graph format or convert from `h5` to `.pb` using [How to export Keras .h5 to tensorflow .pb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45466020/how-to-export-keras-h5-to-tensorflow-pb)

2) Convert `.pb` to `tflite` as described by me here: https://medium.com/@prashantdandriyal7/darknet-to-tensorflow-to-tensorflowlite-b783d55b106a