# How we can convert keras model .h5 file to tensorflow saved model (.pb) mask rcnn

Tags: tensorflow, keras, sos

How to convert keras mask rcnn model to tensorflow ?
File url: https://nomeroff.net.ua/models/mrcnn/mask_rcnn_numberplate_1000_2019_10_07.h5

Comment: Have you checked this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45466020/how-to-export-keras-h5-to-tensorflow-pb

Comment: yes, Error : ValueError: No model found in config file.

Comment: Did you save the whole model or just the weights?